# Not able to play multiple sounds at the same time in swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios9, avaudioplayer

I'm using Xcode 7.3.1 and iOS 9.3.4.
I have tried all the code in the following URLs, but nothing solved the problem. Anyone facing the same problem?

[AVAudioPlayer Help: Playing multiple sounds simultaneously, stopping them all at once, and working around Automatic Reference Counting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11194838/avaudioplayer-help-playing-multiple-sounds-simultaneously-stopping-them-all-at)

[Playing Multiple Sounds at Once Using AVAudioPlayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27681276/playing-multiple-sounds-at-once-using-avaudioplayer)

[Playing multiple sounds simultaneously with AVAudioPlayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6286574/playing-multiple-sounds-simultaneously-with-avaudioplayer)

[Play multiple sounds (one by one) with AVAudioPlayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16453706/play-multiple-sounds-one-by-one-with-avaudioplayer)

[AVAudioPlayer not playing sounds simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20064041/avaudioplayer-not-playing-sounds-simultaneously)

[How to Play multiple audio files simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28299679/how-to-play-multiple-audio-files-simultaneously)

[Playing multiple sounds at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5412940/playing-multiple-sounds-at-once)

Comment: Have you tried adding multiple AVAudioPlayers and have them each play one sound instead of one AVAudioPlayer playing multiple sounds?

Comment: Have a look at my answer to a very similar question (I was quite thorough) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36865233/get-avaudioplayer-to-play-multiple-sounds-at-a-time/36865967#36865967

Comment: If the class in my answer doesn't work would you mind posting some of your code so I can see what the problem might be?